# Are there allusions to Blade Runner in Alias?

Tags: reference, blade-runner, alias

I am rewatching the Bad Robot TV series *Alias*. I'm on season five with the episode titled *The Horizon*. There is a scene that features Kelly Payton (Amy Acker) whom has now taken over operations for the previously deceased, Gordon Dean. The scene starts out with her eating **Asian noodles** sitting at an **outdoor** restaurant, talking with an Asian employee, in the middle of a huge **downpour of rain**, before she suddenly sees her **target** and begins to follow them through the crowd.

[image: Alias 5.09]

[image: Alias Kelly Payton]

[image: Alias]

I know for a **fact** that other Bad Robot works have mass allusions to *Blade Runner*, especially *Fringe* and *Almost Human*, but because *Alias* existed before the idea of massively searching for Easter eggs was a popular thing, there isn't a lot of works sited to officially prove some of *Alias*'s possible references/allusions (outside of *Run Lola Run*).

Some other possible allusions:

- Character named Sloan(e)
- Project Helix (genetic mutation technology) is a kind of equivalent to false-identity and kinds of cloning.
- The Horizon (Rambaldi Artifact) and Project Black Hole (collection of Rambaldi Artifacts) seem to facilitate metaphysics with kinds of time-travel or time-knowledge-transference in *Alias* and if I remember right I believe *Blade Runner* touched on an *Event Horizon*. I think people speculate *Alien* and *Blade Runner* may co-exist in same universe or linked universes.

I just would like to find **a credible source** that confirms *Blade Runner* as a reference in *Alias* with either this specific sequence or in general.